# Does Oracle Wallet manager exist in XE

Tags: ssl, plsql, oracle11g

I installed Oracle XE on my Windows environment, i created a procedure to send SMS (to invoke a WS) the problem is that i have url with HTTPS (with ssl encryption) so i need to add the certificate , based on reasearchs i made , i found that i have to use Oracle Wallet Manager to add the certificate to a wallet (**OWM**) to use it later with UTL_HTTP. but i didn't find the **OWM** in my installation , My questions:
does this OWM exist in XE edition?
is there any other way to add certificate without the wallet way ?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Wallet manager ships together with Oracle client.

Just install the client software, e.g. Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client, and Wallet manager must be located in Integrated Management Tools section.